# Azure Front Door service ignores 403 - app stopped error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I have a Front Door service configured for my 2 services, one is an Azure App Service, second an AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Both hosts provided using host address.

I stop my Azure App Service on purpose (which has priority 1 in my config) to check if Front Door redirects the traffic to AWS.

The stopped service returns 403 - app stopped response, nevertheless Front Door doesn't redirect the traffic to AWS and keeps displaying the primary service with 403 error.

config:

```
healthy probes configured properly,
both HTTP and HTTPS enabled,
priorities set,
probe intervals 10 sec
```

Comment: What is the routing rule configuration? Is there different PATTERNS TO MATCH?

Comment: @NancyXiong standard "/*", both services host the same software

Comment: Could you verify this `If health probes fail for every backend in a backend pool, then Front Door considers all backends healthy and routes traffic in a round robin distribution across all of them.`? Check if AWS Elastic Beanstalk is also unhealthy. refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-health-probes#how-front-door-determines-backend-health).

Comment: @NancyXiong I checked the metrics of health in Azure Monitor and everything is fine. The working service is operational (due to probe) and the second is down

Comment: Now on the turned of service I'm getting 404 response

Answer (score 0):

When you want to verify that if one backend is unavailable then the front door will redirect traffic to other backends. There are [four main concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-routing-methods) to traffic routing available in Front Door:

- **Available backends**. All backends are healthy then health check will pass. If health probes fail for every backend in a backend pool, then Front Door considers all backends healthy and routes traffic in a round-robin distribution across all of them. See [How Front Door determines backend health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-health-probes#how-front-door-determines-backend-health)
- **Priority**. By default, Front Door sends traffic only to the top priority backends (**lowest value for priority**) that is, the primary set of backends.
- **Latency**. Select the backends with latency range (least latency & latency sensitivity in ms specified). By default, the latency sensitivity property is set to `0` ms, that is, always forward the request to the fastest available backend.
- **Weights**. This parameter uses a default weight of '50'.

In this case, you could use the same conditions above, put the two backends in the same backend pool. Make sure both backends are availability then you can stop one backend.

For the 404 error in your comment, there are several possible causes for this symptom:

> The backend is not a public facing backend and is not visible to the
>   Front Door service.
>
> The backend is misconfigured, which is causing the Front Door service
>   to send the wrong request (that is, your backend only accepts HTTP but
>   you have not unchecked allowing HTTPS so Front Door is attempting to
>   forward HTTPS requests).
>
> The backend is rejecting the host header that was forwarded with the
>   request to the backend.
>
> The configuration for the backend has not yet been fully deployed.

You could get more details of [troubleshooting Steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-troubleshoot-routing#troubleshooting-steps-1) for this error.

Comment: But I stil expect a master-slave (main-backup) configuration. That's why I set priorities like 1 and 2. Nevertheless the service doesn't respect them. Of course both addresses in 1 backend pool. Both weight 50.

Comment: Maybe I should change the Latency sensitivity from 0 to enable priority traffic?

Comment: Try set priorities equal. As I know, if you set the Priority, for an initial connection, the client preferably selects the high priority backend. If you do not set priority, backend usually round-robin for each new connection. For backends failover, You can see this demo [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YV2nYfWfgAk) and this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door#prerequisites).`instances run in Active/Active mode, that is, either of them can take traffic at any time, unlike a Active/Stand-By configuration where one acts as a failover.`